# Dreamweaver tells me that it can't edit some html file because it is locked, how to exclude folders/types from auto lock?

Tags: macos, versions

Dreamweaver complains that it can't edit some specific files due to the fact that they are locked. With as only options to cancel or view read-only. However I do really want to edit the .html files. This started some weeks/months after upgrading from Mac OS X Lion 10.7 to Mavericks 10.9.

#### Automatic File Locking in Mac OS X

I know that this file auto locking might be in place due to an [OS X Lion "Auto Save and Versions" feature](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4753). However in Mavericks I can no longer see the "Lock documents [2 weeks] after last edit" in "System Preferences > Time Machine > Options".

#### Manual file lock removal

The file locks can be removed from the command line using a command like:

```
$ sudo chflags -vR nouchg ~/Sites
```

I don't want to turn off the OS X "file auto lock" feature completely. For at least Pages and Numbers documents I would like to preserve "file auto lock". How can I turn off this automatic file locking for selected folders or file types/extensions?

Comment: Just curious, can you manually unlock files by opening them in Finder, option+click them, selecting "Get Info" and then unlocking them there?

Comment: @bassplayer7 Opening the file information from Finder, did keep the "Lock" check box not enabled. Even after unlocking by clicking on the lock icon and entering an admin account plus password details.